# Error on Presenting FDTake

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I got a error on Presenting FDTake ([Github-Link](https://github.com/fulldecent/FDTake/)) FROM a PRESENTED TableViewController:

Warning: Attempt to present UIImagePickerController: 0x14454a880 on NavigationViewController: 0x14452f900 whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

NavigationViewController is a subclass of UINavigationController. It's from REMenu (https://github.com/romaonthego/REMenu).

Any Idea how I can solve it? I already wrote a Issue to the repository but nobody answered, so I thought maybe you guys know why.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used that library though I can share my code for the same functionality with you. Feel free to use it whereever you were using FDTake. Don't forget to set Actionsheet and UIImagePickerController Delegates.

```
-(IBAction)chooseProfilePicture:(id)sender
{ 
    UIActionSheet *filterActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Operation"
                                                                   delegate:self
                                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                     destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Choose from gallery", @"Take Photo", nil];

    [filterActionSheet showInView:self.view];
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    UIImagePickerController *imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
     imgPicker.delegate = self;
     imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;


    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0:
            [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:imgPicker animated:YES];
            break;
        case 1:
            if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
                 UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
            {
                imgPicker.sourceType =
                UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
                imgPicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
                imgPicker.allowsEditing = NO;
                [self presentViewController:imgPicker
                                   animated:YES completion:nil];
                //_newMedia = YES;
            }

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    //Do what you want with the captured/selected image

}
```

It's that simple. Not really a need for using third party libs for that. Not an answer to your question but it is relevant in some fashion.